# Group objects based on property name and type

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an array as per below;

```
var myArray = {
    "cartItems": {"paramA1": 25, "paramA2": 35},
    "cartShippingCost": {"paramB1": 4, "paramB2": 152, "paramB3": 536, "paramB4": 56},
    "cartNo": 675765,
    "cartSpecialRequirements": {"paramC1": 432},
    "cartPostage": {"paramD1": 56, "paramD2": 6537},
    "cartId": 54,
    "tel": 7778798548,
    "status": 5465465,
    "delivery": 65464646686674
};

var cartItems;
```

I perform a loop over myArray to find the objects who' key contains 'cart'

```
for (var key in myArray) {
    if (myArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (key.indexOf('cart') > -1) {
            alert(key + " -> " + o[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Which works great. I want to retrieve objects:

- with keys containing 'cart'
- and is of type structure, e.g.from the above, `cartNo` and `cartId` are NOT of type structures.
- push the 'cart' structures type in to cartItems;

Comment: Try `filter()` then `map()`

Comment: `myArray` should be an object, in my opinion

Comment: @DerberAlter - it is, sorry, my mistake. Take a look at myArray again ive changed it.

Comment: @elclanrs - myArray structure has changed, please see the above.

Comment: what is your real data-structure? That thing you posted is no valid JS, neither a valid Object nor a valid Array.

Comment: @Thomas please see the updated structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

```
var data = {
    "cartItems": {"paramA1": 25, "paramA2": 35},
    "cartShippingCost": {"paramB1": 4, "paramB2": 152, "paramB3": 536, "paramB4": 56},
    "cartNo": 675765,
    "cartSpecialRequirements": {"paramC1": 432},
    "cartPostage": {"paramD1": 56, "paramD2": 6537},
    "cartId": 54,
    "tel": 7778798548,
    "status": 5465465,
    "delivery": 65464646686674
}

var cartObjects = [];
for(var k in data){
    var v = data[k];
    if(v && typeof v === "object" && k.indexOf("cart") !== -1 && data.hasOwnProperty(k)){
        cartObjects.push(v);
    }
}

console.log(cartObjects)
```

Comment: Thank you, with the above, i get ReferenceError: obj is not defined

Comment: I think ```obj``` should be ```data```

Comment: Correct, data works, i am left with an object without the key, so {"paramA1": 25, "paramA2": 35} and its parent: cartItems is missing

Comment: You could simply change ```var cartObjects = []``` to ```var cartObjects = {}``` and ```cartObjects.push(v)``` with ```cartObjects[k]=v```

Comment: That seems better, thank you. Was there something else you wanted to say? Noticed you ended on 'and'..

Comment: Nope, just left that by mistake while making an edit ;)

Comment: I just wanted to point out, you could write your code in ES6 style and then transpile it using something like Babel http://babeljs.io/ to support older browsers.

Comment: fixed the ReferenceError: obj is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a variable is an object (structure as you said) by using `typeof(var)`. In your case, you could do something like this in your loop :

```
if (typeof(myArray[key]) == 'object')
{
    // do something
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to first filter your object for keys which contain 'cart' and they reference properties of type 'object'.  Then map them to the referenced object.  This will result in an array of objects.

```
var cartItems = Object.keys(myArray)
    .filter(key => {
        return key.indexOf('cart') > -1 && typeof myArray[key] === 'object';
    })
    .map(key => {
        return myArray[key];
    });
```

Comment: thank you, this is using a lot of ES6.. Do you know ES5 friendly as i support IE8!

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  If you need to support IE8, then @Thomas answer should do what you want as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this

```js
var myArray = {
    "cartItems": {"paramA1": 25, "paramA2": 35},
    "cartShippingCost": {"paramB1": 4, "paramB2": 152, "paramB3": 536, "paramB4": 56},
    "cartNo": 675765,
    "cartSpecialRequirements": {"paramC1": 432},
    "cartPostage": {"paramD1": 56, "paramD2": 6537},
    "cartId": 54,
    "tel": 7778798548,
    "status": 5465465,
    "delivery": 65464646686674
};

var result = Object.keys(myArray).reduce(function (p, c) { 
  var value = myArray[c]; 
  if (c === "cartItems" || c.indexOf("cart") < 0) { return p; }
  
  if (["string", "number", "boolean"].indexOf(typeof value) > -1) {
    p.push(value);
  }
  return p;
}, []);

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```